# How to display data in datagrid view of user logged in c# sql

Tags: c#, sql

Hi I am having a problem when trying to update my datagrid view so that it displays only the data of the user who is logged in.

I have two tables, one called records and one called users. The users table contains user data including username and user id. the records table contains user id as a foreign key and data about bmi readings.

I have a login page which when logged in displays a message which is welcome (username)

This is the code I have written to update the datagridview

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@(removed to simplify)); 

con.Open();

var sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Records WHERE UserID=@UserID", con);

sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", currentUsernameLabel.Text);

DataSet DATA = new dataGridView.DataSource = 

con.Close();
```

How do I look up what the userID is, (based on the username which is stored in currentUsernameLabel.Text) so that I can add it as a parameter?

EDIT: 
these are my tables:

Records table

[image: Records table]

---

Users table

[image: Users table]

---

Please let me know if you need anymore information in order to help

**EDIT:**

I have come up with the following solution:

```
//Find ID of user who is logged in
string currentUserID;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\n0740572\Projects\newest\CW\CW\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select UserID from Users where Username = '"+currenUsernameLabel.Text+"' ", conn);
try
{
conn.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read())
{
currentUserID = reader["UserID"].ToString();
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentUserID", currentUserID);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
reader.Close();
} catch (SqlException ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
} finally
{
conn.Close();
}

//update datagridview
this.recordsTableAdapter.ChartAll(this.recordsDataSet.Records);

}
```

The ChartAll query is as follows:

```
SELECT Height, Weight, BMI, Date FROM dbo.Records
WHERE UserID = @CurrentUserID
```

The error message is : 
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebGjN.png)

Has it got something to do with needing the parameter to be an int not a string?

Comment: Your code is incomplete.  That said, what exactly happens when you run your code?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Are you getting some error or you are getting unexpected output? Please show us some sample records, what you expect and what is the actual result. You can edit your question to include these details.

Comment: It comes up with an error because the currentUsernameLabel.Text is the username not the userID so it cannot look up the corresponding records of that userID.

Comment: Thanks for help will edit question as best as I can now

Comment: you need to call Fill method of SQlDataAdapter

Answer (score 0):

```
            var table = new DataTable("myTable");
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstring"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Records", con);
                da.Fill(ds, "Records");
            }
        }
        dataGridViewPerson.DataSource = table.DefaultView;
```

get your connectionstring from the config file, change the code to match your code, otherwise you wont learn. aka use and fill a DataTable

Comment: Thanks for help but unfortunately I didn't use your answer as I am graded on the project and I need to demo and explain it and unfortunately I got a bit lost. Would you mind having a look at the solution I have made and how to fix it? I will edit the question now